# total Number of rectangles in a grid?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Here i want to count the total numbers of rectangles in M*N grid. This code is working properly but not for the large input like M=100000 N=100000. It shows something like -nan or any negative integer.
Thee result will be the modulo of 1000000007. How can i get an accurate answer with this large integer range?
Thank you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double factorial(int);

int main(){
  int m,n;
  double mod= 1000000007; 
    double p,q,result;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the dimensions of grid: "; 
    cin>>m>>n;
    if (m <0&&n<0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid dimensions!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    m++; n++; /*if n is the no of vertical/horizontal boxes,
                there will be n+1 vertical/horizontal lines in the grid */
    result=(factorial(m)/(2*factorial(m-2)))*(factorial(n)/(2*factorial(n-2)));
    cout<<"\nThe rectangles in the grid is:"<<fmod(result,mod);
    return 0;
}

double factorial(int x) {
    double temp;
    if(x <= 1) return 1;
    temp = x * factorial(x - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double factorial(int);

int main(){
  int m,n;
  double mod= 1000000007; 
    double p,q,result;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the dimensions of grid: "; 
    cin>>m>>n;
    if (m <0&&n<0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid dimensions!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    m++; n++; /*if n is the no of vertical/horizontal boxes,
                there will be n+1 vertical/horizontal lines in the grid */
   //This is where I had the typo. Forgot to divide by 2.
    result=((m*(m-1))/2)*((n*(n-1))/2);
    cout<<"\nThe rectangles in the grid is:"<<fmod(result,mod);
    return 0;
}

/*double factorial(int x) {
    double temp;
    if(x <= 1) return 1;
    temp = x * factorial(x - 1);
    return temp;
} */
```

This should work fine. There was no need for you to implement a factorial function. You can have just simplified your statement down and you would have gotten your answer.

Comment: but now it is showing the wrong answer. lets say M=3 N=4 and the answer should be 60 but it shows 180.

Comment: I just had a small typo I reduced the expression down on paper and forgot to divide by 2. It should work pretty fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do 100000 factorial in a double-precision number, you'll get overflow (as you've observed).

In your case think about this expansion of what you're calculating

```
 m * (m-1) * (m-2) * (m-3) * ... * 2 * 1
-----------------------------------------
         2 * (m-2) * (m-3) * ... * 2 * 1
```

This all simplifies to m * (m-1) / 2.  So, you don't need your factorial function at all.

Edit: The code in another post was not right.  Try this:

```
result = static_cast<double>(m) * (m-1) * n * (n-1) / 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really programming related, but `factorial(m)/(2*factorial(m-2)` is the same as `m * (m-1) / 2` which will probably not cause an overflow.